# Could Karjakin have grabbed on g5 at move 56 against Anand in the Candidates 2014?

Tags: analysis, endgame, anand, karjakin

After 55...Rb2, we got the following position in Karjakin - Anand (Candidates 2014, round 13). Well, how about Nxg5, does it work?

```
[White "Karjakin"]
[Black "Anand"]
[FEN "8/8/6k1/4p1p1/4P1Pp/5P1N/1r1BK3/8 w - - 0 1"]

1.Nxg5 Rxd2+ 2.Kxd2 Kxg5 3.Ke3 h3 4.Kf2 Kf4 5.Kg1 Kg5 6.Kh1
```

Seems better (winning?) for white. Am I missing something?

Comment: Karjakin also thought h3 was forced and only calculated that line. He missed Kf6 and Kh6. Kg6 loses.

Comment: What amazes me is that a world class grandmaster like Karjakin failed to correctly evaluate this endgame. It should have been "elementary" for him.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

3...h3 is wrong. The key is 3...Kf6!

```
[FEN "8/8/5k2/4p3/4P1Pp/4KP2/8/8 w - - 2 4"]
```

Note that:

- White's king has to stay in the h-pawn's square, so it can't try to walk around the pawns.
- Once white's king gets to h3, black should always be able to answer ...Kg5. If he does, then white's king can only retreat, unless he tries f4 there:

```
[FEN "8/8/8/4p1k1/4P1Pp/5P1K/8/8 w - - 8 7"]

1.f4 exf4
```

If anyone is better off here, it's black, but it's still a draw.

- Or white can play 4.f4 immediately.

```
[FEN "8/8/5k2/4p3/4P1Pp/4KP2/8/8 w - - 2 4"]

4.f4 h3! 5.fxe5+ {What else?} Kxe5 6.Kf3 h2 7.Kg2 h1=Q+ 8.Kxh1 Kxe4 =
```

So the pawn endgame is a draw.

Comment: You suggested `3... Kf6`, I suggested `3... Kh6`. Both moves work equally fine, what black should avoid is `3... Kg6?` because of `3... Kg6? 4. f4 h3 5. f5+`.

Answer (score 5):

The pawn endgame is a draw. Black doesn't play `h3` until white plays `f4`, for instance

```
[White "Karjakin"]
[Black "Anand"]
[FEN "8/8/8/4p1k1/4P1Pp/5P2/3K4/8 w - - 0 1"]

3.Ke3 Kh6 4. f4 h3! 5. Kf3 exf4
```

If white doesn't play `f4`, then black only needs to be ready to answer `Kh3` with `Kg5`, but that is never going to be a problem.